# Renaming Core Data class

Tags: core-data

I have an application that uses CoreData.

I previously had a class named Marker which was linked to the Marker entity in Core Data.

I renamed the Marker class to CoreDataMarker. So I created a new .xcdatamodel file with the new class name for the entity. Then I created a .xcmappingmodel and selected the old and the new .xcdatamodel files and it seemed to 'auto-setup' fine.

However, when I run my application it complains with: "Can't merge models with two different entities named 'Marker'". I understand that this happens, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Do you know how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need a new xcdatamodel. Change the in the "Class" field in the entity description for your `Marker` entity to `CoreDataMarker`. That's all that's needed. The implementing class information does not require a schema migration.

Comment: Do you know whether I should update only the current xcdatamodel version or all historic versions?

Answer (score 0):

And make sure **ONLY the current version** of the data model (latest xcdatamodel file) is included in target **and mapping model file**. It looks like putting other model files are being done automatically based on information from xcmappingmodel file.

It is unintuitive but this was what worked for me.