# Redefinition of as a different kind of symbol in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

We have a class `WayPoint`. But at some point, we decided to rename the class to `Placemark`. However, we don't really want to change the name of the class because it will result in a lot of modification of the existing code. Therefore, I added one line of `typedef` at the bottom of the header file and start using `Placemark` in any new code happily ever since.

```
@interface WayPoint : _WayPoint
@end
typedef WayPoint Placemark;
```

But there is still one thing that I don't understand. If I try to use the forward definition in some other header file. I can only used:

```
@class WayPoint;
```

If I use:

```
@class Placemark;
```

I will get the error message:

> Redefinition of 'Placemark' as a different kind of symbol

Why?

Comment: Interesting question, my answer provides alternatives, bot doesn't answer the question as is. I have some guesses, but I'm not that sure to post them here. I'm curious about the low level details as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why can't you use Xcode's refactoring features (Simple Rename does it fast and easy). But if you really want to do this you may use something better then typedef:

```
@compatibility_alias Placemark WayPoint
```

Comment: The reason is that this class is automatically generated by Core Data. I am not sure whether it is safe to refactor it. But good point. I will have a look at this.

Comment: @YuchenZhong You can, guess it will even update class in entitiy settings. Quick search gives this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1359960/1032151

Answer (score 5):

> Because typedef Placemark is an alias and you are trying to use it as a class
>   symbol.

So error clearly indicates 
**Redefinition of 'Placemark' as a different kind of symbol** 
which means your class name and typedef alias are different symbol.

Comment: typedef WayPoint Placemark; is not an object, it's just an alias of WayPoint.