# Name conflict with Realm "Size" object when using Swift and Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

I have a project named 'Foo' that is mostly Swift, but there is one objective-c view controller. When I include 'Foo-Swift.h' in ObjectiveCViewController.m I get this error:

"Redefinition of 'Size' as different kind of symbol"

This is because I have a Realm Object called 'Size'. The simple solution here is to rename my Realm Object FooSize or something similar - but is there a slicker way to do this? I'm not familiar with every last Swift feature and I wonder if there is some kind of namespace type thing I could use, or similar feature.

Comment: May it can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632576/redefinition-of-as-a-different-kind-of-symbol-in-objective-c/26632745

Comment: This "@compatibility_alias" business, while interesting, I do not think it is what I need. But it is the kind of thing I am talking about.